# Перевод из string в datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, формат

Есть формат даты "вт, окт 12 2021 10:22 AM" данная строка берется из dataframe, который загружается из excel файла. При попытке перевода из строки в тип данных datetime выдает ошибку не совпадения форматов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
p = pd.DataFrame(calls.groupby("Дата звонка"))
for data in p[0]:
    print(data)
    data = datetime.datetime.strptime(data, "%a, %b %d %Y %I:%M %p")
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: У меня работает только если обрезать формат времени AM, добавить локаль `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "rus_rus")`, `date = datetime.strptime(date[:-3], "%a, %b %d %Y %H:%M")`

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае придется воспользоваться "костылем", т.к. русская "локаль" не понимает модификаторов `AM/PM`.

Рабочий пример:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')

df = pd.DataFrame({"d": ["вт, окт 12 2021 10:22 AM", "вт, окт 12 2021 04:22 PM"]})
df["res"] = (pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df["d"].str[:-9], 
                            format="%a, %b %d %Y").dt.strftime("%Y-%d-%m") 
             + df["d"].str[-9:]))
```

результат:

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]:
                          d                 res
0  вт, окт 12 2021 10:22 AM 2021-12-10 10:22:00
1  вт, окт 12 2021 04:22 PM 2021-12-10 16:22:00
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте что именно вы вычитываете из книги. Вполне может оказаться что вам прилетает unixtime, который при отображении в экселе форматируется в указанную строку.
2. Проверьте что все строки заполнены и заполнены датой. Возможно, гдето пусто или вместо даты строка.
3. Вероятно, что дело в локали. Попробуйте почитать [там](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32785195/1597497)

Comment: Хотя это больше тянет на комментарий. Если только вдруг угадаете причину...

Comment: Проверил. Из dataframe прилетает тип данных string. Со всех строк. да и если в типе данных была ошибка python бы ругался на это, а тут ошибка именно в том что выставленный мой шаблон не совпадает с такой датой. Но я вроде все верно проставил

Comment: А что именно то прилетает вам? Вы так и не показали. (если вдруг оно на картинке то правильно сказали - лучше текстом. Не у всех картинки могут загружаться. У меня нопример ктото из админов трафик экономит)

Comment: Вот проверяю на тип данных, каждая запись - строка
p = pd.DataFrame(calls.groupby("Дата звонка"))
for data in p[0]:
    print(type(data))
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>

Comment: Понятно что класс - строка. Я спрашиваю - __какая__ строка?

Comment: "вт, окт 12 2021 10:22 AM" вот такая

Comment: когда данную строку помещаешь для изменения в datetime, ставишь шаблон
%a, %b %d %Y %I:%M %p то он пишет что шаблон не верный, хотя по другому я даже не представляю как можно описать данную строку

Comment: Возможно, дело в локали. Дополнил ответ.